# RVM can't install jruby-1.6.6

Tags: ruby, macos, rvm, jruby

I'm trying to use RVM to install jruby-1.6.6 to run a legacy application.

I am having trouble because every time I go to install I get an error message and a broken jruby:

```
$ rvm install jruby-1.6.6
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
Found remote file http://jruby.org.s3.amazonaws.com/downloads/1.6.6/jruby-bin-1.6.6.tar.gz
Checking requirements for osx.
Requirements installation successful.
jruby-1.6.6 - #configure
jruby-1.6.6 - #download
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 14.7M  100 14.7M    0     0   237k      0  0:01:03  0:01:03 --:--:--  204k
No checksum for downloaded archive, recording checksum in user configuration.
jruby-1.6.6 - #validate archive
jruby-1.6.6 - #extract
jruby-1.6.6 - #validate binary
jruby-1.6.6 - #setup
jruby-1.6.6 - #making binaries executable.
RVM can not install rubygems for older jruby, select other ruby and try again.
expr: syntax error
```

After I run this, I get:

```
$ rvm list

rvm rubies

   jruby-1.6.6 [ broken ]
```

which is no fun.

I just says "RVM can't do this" but I can't find out *why*. Any help at all will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since it's legacy - you might need a legacy version of RVM as well (or simply try latest RVM) ... I can confirm RVM still installs **jruby-1.6.8** fine (which is really close to 1.6.6 and even as it's legacy it's probably really worth updating from 1.6.6), otherwise I would not expect this to work and [download 1.6.6 directly](http://jruby.org/files/downloads/1.6.6/index.html) unzip it and roll.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it turns out 1.6.8 doesn't want to load either.  It seems to be just the gems it was having trouble with.  I  have avoided the problem (enough to get my legacy app at least turning over) by `gem install bundler && bundle install`.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

I got it working acceptably by running `rvm install jruby-1.6.6 --create`. I'm not sure why.